# ASP.NET MVC giving Validation Failed Error

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unobtrusive-validation

I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC4 web application. My database is at Hostgator (so it is not a local host). The website is running very very very slow, even in my computer (while using VS2012). To many times i'm having a Validation Failed errors (you can see it down there), in some forms that most of the times actually works. I'm suspecting it to be a problem with some connectivity to the database (I am using Entity Framework 6), maybe the session overs much to fast, or some other issues. Maybe the two problems ({1} Running very slow. {2} Validation errors in forms randomaly, 30% of the times.) are related?

**Edit:**
I also have validation annotations. If some input is missing i'm catching it in client side. The problems is I am entering the same info in the forms. sometimes it works, sometimes its not...

```
###Server Error in '/' Application.###

Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details. The validation errors are: The FirstName field is required.; The LastName field is required.; The FirstName field is required.; The LastName field is required.; The FirstName field is required.; The LastName field is required.; The FirstName field is required.; The LastName field is required.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details. The validation errors are: The FirstName field is required.; The LastName field is required.; The FirstName field is required.; The LastName field is required.; The FirstName field is required.; The LastName field is required.; The FirstName field is required.; The LastName field is required.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[DbEntityValidationException: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details. The validation errors are: The FirstName field is required.; The LastName field is required.; The FirstName field is required.; The LastName field is required.; The FirstName field is required.; The LastName field is required.; The FirstName field is required.; The LastName field is required.]
   RentalsForceProject.DAL.UnitOfWork.Save() +490
   RentalsForceProject.Controllers.LeadController.Create(CreateLeadViewModel model) +205
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +118
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +261
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41() +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +124
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +838059
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +33
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +838644
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +65
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +51
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +51
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```